# How to most efficiently splice an array while looping through a list of indices of to be removed array items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, mutation

I am doing a multi-select delete images feature in my image gallery project(Vue project).

Here's the code for it...

```
data{
    images: [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
}

methods: {
    multiDelete(){
        let toDeleteIndexes = [3, 4, 1, 2];
        
        for(let index of toDeleteIndicies)
            this.images.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

> 1st iteration:
>
> index: 3
>
> before splice: [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5,
> image6];
>
> after splice:  [image0, image1, image2, image4, image5, image6];

> 2nd iteration:
>
> index: 4
>
> before splice: [image0, image1, image2, image4, image5, image6];
>
> after splice:  [image0, image1, image2, image4, image6];

In 2nd iteration I want image4 to be removed but the after the splice the length of the array and hence elements shift.

But I want the elements to be removed based on the initial images array (i.e. I want image3, image4, image1, image2 to be removed from the array in this case).

The only method I can think of right now is to sort the toDeleteIndexes in descending order and then splice through the loop.

Is there a better and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The OP is looking for ...

> *... a better and fast way ...*

... of removing items from an array by mutating this array by repeatedly processed `slice` tasks/methods.

This method is expensive because all items right from the sliced positions need to be shifted accordingly after the slicing has taken place. Thus the best way of removing items from an array is to run the `slice`/***remove*** always **from right to left**. Even better was, to somehow combine the removal of items which are to each other direct predecessors and/or successors.

As for the OP's problem of a given position list of to be removed items, one could run a task which creates a list of slice ranges.

Especially for arrays which contain a huge amount of items and also need to be mutated quite heavily, running all remove tasks according to the before created scheme might pay off in a better performance.

```js
function createRemoveScheme(indexList, targetList) {
  return Array
    .from(indexList)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce((schema, currentPos, idx, referenceList) => {

      const { rangeList } = schema;
      let range;

      const recentPos = referenceList[idx - 1] ?? null;
      const nextPos = referenceList[idx + 1] ?? null;

      const isOpenNewRange = (
        (recentPos === null) ||
        (currentPos - recentPos !== 1)
      );
      const isTerminateRange = (recentPos !== null) && (
        (nextPos === null) ||
        (nextPos - currentPos !== 1)
      );

    if (isOpenNewRange) {

      range = [ currentPos ];
      rangeList.push(range);
    }
    if (isTerminateRange) {

      range = rangeList[rangeList.length - 1];
      range.push(currentPos);
    }
    return schema;

  }, { target: targetList, rangeList: [] });
}


const imageList = [
  'image0', 'image1', 'image2',
  'image3', 'image4', 'image5',
  'image6'
];
const deletionIndexList = [3, 4, 1, 2];

console.log(
  'createRemoveScheme([9,8,7,11,5,2,4,1,3], []) ...',
  createRemoveScheme([9,8,7,11,5,2,4,1,3], [])
);
console.log(
  'createRemoveScheme(deletionIndexList, imageList) ...',
  createRemoveScheme(deletionIndexList, imageList)
);
console.log(
  'unmutated original image list ...',
  { imageList }
);


[
  createRemoveScheme(deletionIndexList, imageList)

].forEach(({ target, rangeList }) => rangeList

  // in order to be able to splice/delete
  // items from each target array's right side.
  .reverse()

  // mutate each of a scheme's original target array.
  .forEach(([idxStart, idxEnd]) =>

    // delete each of a target array's range of items.
    target.splice(idxStart, (idxEnd - idxStart + 1))
  )
);

console.log(
  'mutated original image list ...',
  { imageList }
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Edit:

OP ...

> *I actually want the original array to be mutated ... and you have reversed the toDeleteIndexes (or deletionIndexList as you mentioned) which I have already figured out but it's not optimal in my opinion but it works*

... just implement the above approach into your code like that ...

```
data{
  images: [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
}

methods: {
  multiDelete() {

    let toDeleteIndexes = [3, 4, 1, 2];

    createRemoveScheme(toDeleteIndexes)
      .rangeList
      .reverse()
      .forEach(([idxStart, idxEnd]) =>

        this.images.splice(idxStart, (idxEnd - idxStart + 1))
      );
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

OP ...

> *can you please explain why are you sorting copy of toDeleteIndexes......and why not sort the original array itself?*

Since the approach and its implementation both are generic, one does not want to mutate any involved object except the to be mutated array. This and the necessity to `sort` the array of to be removed indices are the reason for creating a shallow copy of the passed array. `createRemoveScheme` just does not mutate what it has no say about.

For example, an array of indices like `[9, 8, 7, 11, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3]` gets passed. A copy of it gets sorted in a numerically ascending way to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11]`. The following reduce process then does create a list of splice ranges by looking into the value differences of direct predecessors/successors of each currently processed splice index. Thus the resulting array of splice ranges will look like this ...

```
[[ 1, 5 ], [ 7, 9 ], [ 11, 11 ]]
```

... and reversed like that ...

```
[[ 11, 11 ], [ 7, 9 ], [ 1, 5 ]]
```

For each splice range the target array now can be processed from right to left like this ...

1. `targetArray.splice(11, (11 - 11 + 1))`
2. `targetArray.splice(7, (9 - 7 + 1))`
3. `targetArray.splice(1, (5 - 1 + 1))`

Comment: I actually want the original array to be mutated.....and you have reversed the toDeleteIndexes (or deletionIndexList as you mentioned) which I have already figured out but it's not optimal in my opinion but it works

Comment: can you please explain why are you sorting copy of toDeleteIndexes......and why not sort the original array itself?

Comment: @ProClasic ... *"interesting approach"* ... thanks, but keep in mind that this approach might squeeze some milliseconds just for a really huge amount of items. Otherwise a `sort` and repeatedly `splice`ing the array from right to left, like with *Nina's* approach, is the preferred way to go.

Comment: FYI ... as direct result of this thread I updated my old gists of prototypal `remove` and `reject` methods ... [Array.reject](https://gist.github.com/petsel/32d7d06a205086c413c3#file-array-reject-js-L142) ... [Array.removeFirstMatch.removeLastMatch.removeEveryMatch.js](https://gist.github.com/petsel/c47c7bd5a2f8ae82e20e7c689cd2fd82#file-array-removefirstmatch-removelastmatch-removeeverymatch-js-L256)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
let toDeleteIndexes = [3, 4, 1, 2];
let images = [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6];

newImages = images.filter((item, i) => !toDeleteIndexes.includes(i))

console.log(newImages); // [image0, image5, image6]
```

`filter` acts on an array and returns an array whose entries satisfy the function given. The first argument, `item`, is each item in the array, and the second argument, `i`, is an optional argument, the index. Here, we're returning the array of all images whose index isn't in `toDeleteIndexes`. It works because you aren't mutating the original array; you're looping through it and creating a new one, hence you don't need to worry about index shifts.

**Edit:** this doesn't seem to work for Vue projects, which is what the OP later revealed. Perhaps this?...

```
let toDeleteIndexes = [3, 4, 1, 2];
let images = [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6];
newImages = images.filter((item, i) => !toDeleteIndexes.includes(i))

images = newImages
```

Comment: i am editing my question that i use vue and it's not working.

Comment: Vue shouldn't affect the code. Could you tell me what your output was?

Comment: when i console.log(this,images) it displayed the initial array

Comment: You don't want to ```console.log(images)``` because ```images``` wasn't changed: A new array was created and you want to use that instead. I edited my code to show that a little easier.

Comment: the thing is Vue makes the array as proxy and you can't use some methods as you would to normal javascript arrays (mabey filter is also one).......I need the `images` to be reactive so I am putting it inside `data()` else your solution would have worked in my opinion.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to act directly on the ```images``` array. So take the result from the filter and set ```images``` equal to it. I've updated my solution. I'm not too familiar with Vue.

Comment: well you've heard me right but vue converts the array or anything inside the `data()`  to a proxy which makes it reactive......but i am not sure why isn't your solution not working (i had high hopes it would)

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the indices and splice from the end.

```js
const
    images = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5', 'image6'],
    indices = [3, 4, 1, 2];

for (const index of indices.sort((a, b) => b - a)) images.splice(index, 1);

console.log(images);
```

Comment: well yes currently that's my code as i mentioned in my problem....but is there a alternative way other than sorting

Comment: what is the problem with sorting an array?

Comment: absolutely no problem but it there more optimal solution (which i don't know) is what i meant to say