# What is the best way to delete objects from Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am wondering if what is the best way to find all Indexes of objects in an Array and then delete them from the Array.
Currently, my code looks like as below;

```
  var data = _.find(group.value, function(valueItem){ return valueItem.value == filter.value });
  var index =_.indexOf(group.value,data);
  group.value.splice(index,1);
```

This works great, but only gets me the first index if the index is more than once. So, I am looking for a method that will get me all indexes in my Array, so I can loop through in remove all

Comment: have a go at this bad boi: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Use filter instead of find

Comment: Thanks but most of it describes how to handle getting simple array stuff not key inside Object in an Array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell Javascript to filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67292134/how-can-i-tell-javascript-to-filter-array-of-objects)

Comment: if the item is an object you can use `item.<property you want> === <value you want>` in the callback.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder `find` and `filter` work similarly. You already have a function that works on an object inside an array--how is `filter` more difficult?

Comment: Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/uxt4s3ef/1/)? @ConfusedCoder

Comment: @Andy if you make it an answer i will accept. As your solution gets me what i need without having to splice array

Comment: Maybe some of the following question's answers do help ... [How to most efficiently splice an array while looping through a list of indices of to be removed array items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303388/how-to-most-efficiently-splice-an-array-while-looping-through-a-list-of-indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array of objects.

Based on your example this code creates new arrays based on the value (name) of each `value` property. I've wrapped the `filter` code in a function (`getData`) that you can call with the original array and the name you want to check as arguments.

If there is no match the function will return an empty array.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, value: 'bob' },
  { id: 2, value: 'dave' },
  { id: 3, value: 'bob' },
  { id: 4, value: 'bob' }
];

function getData(arr, name) {
  return arr.filter(obj => obj.value === name);
}

console.log(getData(arr, 'bob'));
console.log(getData(arr, 'dave'));
console.log(getData(arr, 'mary'));
```

Comment: I would almost always go with this, but I would point out that if you *must* act only on the original array, this won't work because of stale references.